# Multiple が in the same sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-が

I found this sentence while reading and I came across 2 が in the same sentence.

認識結果｛にんしきけっか｝が保存｛ほぞん｝されていない登録｛とうろく｝画像｛がぞう｝があります。

Is it there a way to phrase is differently?

How is this clause divided?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a description of a bug in software or a system. Something like: "There are images registered without recognition results" or more literally "There are registered images for which recognition results were not saved."

Without context it is hard to tell if it was pattern, face, or file format recognition, what exactly "registered image" means, or if this was really a claim. Without this information the above English sentence might sound odd.

The particles が are in two separate clauses here:

- Main clause: 登録画像があります "there are registered images"
- Subordinate
  clause: 認識結果が保存されていない "results of recognition are not saved"

Comment: I was closing an OCR software after extracting the text from the image without savind and this popped up.